# Postfix - mail forwarding not ok - rejected by the server for domain example.com by subdomain mail.example.com

Tags: postfix

Some information:

```
example.com has a MX-record with priority 10,20 and 30 to mail.example.com
mail.example.com has an A-record to 192.0.2.0 (fictional ip)
```

This is my main.cf of postfix

```
#See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, WP-NewBase-052814, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 192.0.2.0/24,127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_alias_domains = mail.example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

This is the error i receive:

```
    Technical details of temporary failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient     
domain example.be by mail.example.com. [192.0.2.0].
```

Any ideas on what i should change to make mailforwarding work? (i have configured incoming mails with forwarding mails (eg. hotmail.com) in the file "virtual", in the Postfix directory

Here are the lines used in virtual

```
webmaster@example.com example_webmaster@hotmail.com
juice@example.com thejuice@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the `8.8.8.8` as a relay? Or trying to setup `virtual_domains`?

Comment: Can you post relevant maillog when rejection happened? Also, you should post **full bounce email** because it will log what's error that returned from your server

Answer (score 1):

**Update 1:** Sorry, I just saw you've defined `virtual_alias_domains`. What are the contents of this file?

Where's `$mydomain`?

You need to tell postfix what domain you're accepting mail for.

```
  mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
```

Note that your config doesn't show `$mydomain` in the `mydestination` parameter.

In your main.cf, include the following:

```
mydomain = example.com
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
```

Also, please don't use Google's DNS as your example IP. It's really confusing, especially if you're testing by sending mail from Gmail.com

A better test is to simply open a telnet session to port 25 of your mail server and manually enter SMTP commands there. (You can find plenty of guides online to telnetting and troubleshooting SMTP).

**Update2** - use a reserved address for your examples - 6.6.6.6 is also a real address.

According to [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737),

> The blocks 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2), and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3) are provided for use in documentation.